# Are binarized rankings problematic as dependent variables?

Tags: econometrics, causality, ranking, probit

I have data on 150 sprint races $r$ and on the rankings and training routines of 20 athletes $i$ who have participated in each race.

I am interested in finding out whether spending more time training is associated with an increased probability of winning a given race. I am thinking of approaching this with the following probit specification:

$First_{ir} = \alpha_{r} + HoursTrained_{i} + \epsilon_{ir}$

Where $First_{ir}$ is a binary variable that is equal to 1 when athlete $i$ has come first in race $r$, $\alpha_{r}$ are race fixed-effects, and $HoursTrained_{i}$ is the amount of time, in hours, that the athlete has trained.

I am wondering whether this setup is problematic due to the fact that I only have one event (i.e. winning the race) and 19 non-events per race?

Answer (score 0):

If you had infinite data that would not have been an issue but in this case I think it really depends on the data distribution. In particular, I would not be too much surprised if your data follows a Pareto-like distribution (i.e. there are few athletes that are winning most of the races), and in that case you would have lot of athletes associated only with one target (that is $First_{ir}=0$ $\forall r$ meaning athlete $i$ never won a race) which would invalidate your analysis. One way to fix this is to create a regression considering the complete ranking, not just a 0-1 variable that represent winning/not winning.

Last point: if your target is to evaluate the performances of training, then I don't think thet $\alpha_r$ is useful since it is a common penalty term for all the athletes.